# How can i add close icon (x) in static popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have static popover, using bootstrap. I want close icon like (x) on title, this should be close (or erase) this popover. this is static one, i dont know how can i make this.

Waiting your helps, thanks already.

Here is my code:

```
<style>
.static-popover .popover {
display: block;
}
</style>

<div class="container static-popover">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="popover bottom">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <h3 class="popover-title">Popover</h3>
            <div class="popover-content">
                <p>Here is some content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/34tsayyL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create `span` element with absolute position then add listener `element.remove()` to remove target element.

```css
.static-popover .popover {
  display: block;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container static-popover">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="popover bottom">
      <div class="arrow"></div>
      <h3 class="popover-title">Popover</h3>
      <span class="close" onclick="document.querySelector('.popover').remove()">x</span>
      <div class="popover-content">
        <p>Here is some content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really? Putting it in a snippet and adding *try this* , isnt really an answer. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
 <button onclick="document.querySelector('.popover').remove()">
  X
 </button>
```

Sinply add some javascript that *erases* the popover.

Answer (score 1):

[Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/34tsayyL/1/) check you fiddle. you need use font awesome.

```
   <h3 class="popover-title">Popover <i class="fa fa-times"></i></h3>


.popover-title i{
  float:right
}
```

updated

```js
$(function(){
 $('.fa-times').on('click',function(){
   $('.popover').hide();
  })
});
```

```css
.static-popover .popover {
display: block;
}

.popover-title i {
  float:right;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container static-popover">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="popover bottom">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <h3 class="popover-title">Popover <i class="fa fa-times"></i></h3>
            <div class="popover-content">
                <p>Here is some content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the x button to the `h3` tag like this :

```
<h3 class="popover-title">Popover <a style='float:right;' class='close_pop'>x</a></h3>
```

and then make the popup `hide` on clicking on x button

```
$('.close_pop').click(function(){
    $('.popover').hide(300);
});
```

and here is your jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/34tsayyL/3/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".close").on('click',function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();

});
```

```css
.static-popover .popover {
display: block;
}

.popover-title span {
float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container static-popover">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="popover bottom">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
              <h3 class="popover-title">Popover <span class="close" >&#9747;</span></h3>
            <div class="popover-content">
                <p>Here is some content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```